# Topologically equivalent metrics, using different definitions.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, equivalent-metrics

I´ve been dealing with topologically equivalent metrics for a while, using the usual definition, that $d$ and $d'$ are topologically equivalent iff they have the same open sets. However, there is another equivalent definition that says that $d$ and $d'$ are topologically equivalent if both $id_{1}:(X,d)\to(X,d')$ and $id_{2}:(X,d)\to(X,d')$ are continuous. Where $X$ is the metric space were both $d$ and $d'$ are defined. However, when trying to use this definition, I don't know If what Im doing is correct. I'll give two examples:

> Decide wether the following are true or false (with $d$, $d'$ topologically equivalent):
>
> a)If $(x_n)$ converges with $d$ then $(x_n)$ converges with $d'$
>
> b)If $(x_n)$ is Cauchy with $d$ then $(x_n)$ is Cauchy with $d'$

For a) I've used the continuity of $id_1$ in the following manner: Given $\epsilon>0$ there exist $\delta>0$ such that $d(x,y)<\delta$ implies $d'(x,y)<\epsilon$. Now I can easily show that $(x_n)$ converges with $d'$.

EDIT

b) We want to see that if $(x_n) $ is Cauchy with $ d$ then it is with $ d'$. That is, I want to see that given $\epsilon_{0} > 0$ there exist $ n_0$ such that $ d'(x_n, x_m) < \epsilon $ if $ n, m \geq n_0$.

Since $ id_1$ is continuous, given $\epsilon_0$ there exist a $\delta_0> 0$ such that $ d (x_n, x_m) <\delta_0$ implies $ d'(x_n, x_m)<\epsilon_0$.

Since $(x_n) $ is Cauchy in $(X, d) $ we have that given $\delta_0 > 0$ there exist $ n_1\in \mathbb {N} $ such that $ d (x_n, x_m)<\delta_0 $ if $ n, m \geq n_0$.

Then taking $ m, n \geq n_1$ we have that $ d (x_n, x_m)<\delta_0$ implying
$ d'(x_n, x_m)<\epsilon_0$.

However I know this proof is wrong, since this would imply completeness is topologically preserved and thats not true!

Comment: You made a mistake in the proof of b) that we can't find without knowing how your proof looks. Also you should specify the quantifiers in the statement you made for a). It should be "Fix $x$ and $\varepsilon>0$, then there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $y$ with $d(x,y)<\delta$ we have $d'(x,y)<\varepsilon$"

Comment: Already edited with my wrong proof!

Comment: Exactly what I was guessing, leaving out the quantifiers in your statements caused you to reach a wrong conclusion. Check the quantifiers in the definition of continuity and apply it very carefully. Note that continuity is different from *uniform* continuity!

Comment: Yes! I realized just after I posted it! Thank you!